# Checking if parsed date is within a date range

Tags: c++, scripting

So I am using a scripting language with c++-like syntax, and I am trying to think of the best way to check if a date is within range. The problem I am running into is that if the current day is in a new month, the check is failing.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
if(iMonth >= iStartMonth && iMonth <= iEndMonth)
{
    if(iDay >= iStartDay && iDay <= iEndDay)
    {
        if(iYear >= iStartYear && iYear <= iEndYear)
        {
                bEnabled = true;
                return;
```

When I have something like this:

```
    Start date: 3 27 2010
    End Date: 4 15 2010
    Current Date: 3 31 2010
```

The day check fails because if (iDay <= iEndDay) does not pass. The scripting language doesn't have a lot of time related functions, and I can't compare timestamps because I'm allowing users to put like "03:27:2010" and "04:15:2010" as start/end dates in a config file. I'm assuming I am just not thinking straight and missing an easy fix.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot code formatting fails when pasted here. Is there any [code] tags or any way to keep formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use [boost::DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/date_time.html) instead of attempting to rewrite the wheel (which when the wheel is a date/time framework it's not as trivial as it may seem). This only if the code you pasted is C++ and not your scripting language (it wasn't clear). Also may I suggest to use [Lua](http://lua.org) instead? :)

---

Anyway the problem is here:

```
if(iDay >= iStartDay && iDay <= iEndDay)
```

You should only check this if iMonth == iStartMonth, and the same for the end month. Otherwise `iDay = 31`, `iEndDay = 15` and 31 <= 15 will fail.

Also you should check for the year first, then the month, then the day.

Comment: Thank you. LUA isn't an option, the game mod uses Pawn which is fine, it is just a bit lacking in some areas.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert all dates to a strings in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and then do lexicographical compares.

Comment: You could even eliminate the dashes - they aren't adding anything to the comparison.

Answer (score 4):

a good way that I found was using the following formula

(year * 10000) + (month * 100) + day

the date 25/09/2013 (day/month/year) becomes 20130925
do it for the start date, end date and the date you want to compare and compare them,
the resulting code will look like this

```
bool isDateInRange(int day, int month, int year, int startDay, int startMonth, int startYear, int endDay, int endMonth, int endYear){
    int entryDate = (year * 10000) + (month * 100) + day;
    int startDate = (startYear * 10000) + (startMonth * 100) + startDay;
    int endDate = (endYear * 10000) + (endMonth * 100) + endDay;

    if (entryDate >= startDate && entryDate <= endDate){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a library that does what you need, or if you prefer to do things yourself, I'm a huge fan of [*Calendrical Calculations*](http://emr.cs.uiuc.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/index.shtml), which shows how to represent each day as an integer, and how to convert back and forth to month/day/year in a *large* number of dating systems.  The integer representation makes adjustment and comparsion trivial—and you get the day of the week by taking the value modulo 7!  The original work was a journal article and has been turned into a book.

I've put [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) code at http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/drop/lua/cal.lua.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here:

The first one is to convert the date and the start/end ranges into `time_t`'s, and then compare them:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tm start, end, day;
// Zero out the struct so that all fields become zero
memset(&start, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
memset(&end, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
memset(&day, 0, sizeof(struct tm));

start.tm_year = 120; // 2020
start.tm_mon = 0; // Jan
start.tm_day = 1;

end.tm_year = 121; // 2021
end.tm_mon = 0; // Jan
end.tm_day = 1;

day.tm_year = 120; // 2020
day.tm_mon = 1; // Feb
day.tm_day = 29;

time_t tstart = mktime(&start);
time_t tend = mktime(&end);
time_t tday = mktime(&day);

tday >= tstart && tday <= tend; // true
```

You can also call `strftime` after converting the days into `struct tm` and use it to make an ISO date as mentioned in the other answer.

A third option is to use `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` and convert the date into the number of hours (for C++17 and older) since the epoch - C++20 has year/month/day types which make this easier.

For example, this is legal in C++20:

```
2021y/1/1 > 2020y/1/1 // true
```

In older versions of C++ you would do something like:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp; // = 2020-01-01
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp2; // = 2021-01-01

auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(tp);

auto d2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(tp2);

d.count() < d2.count(); // true, year 2020 is before 2021
```

The disadvantage of the pre-C++20 syntax is that it's really hard to construct dates, even if you can guarantee the epoch of the clock is e.g. 1970, because you have to deal with leap years and variable-length months. Hence why you should use a 3rd-party datetime library that can deal with this stuff, why I made xDateTime ([github repo](https://github.com/ZenulAbidin/xDateTime) - I even made a date-time period class), or why you should simply migrate your codebase to C++20.

If you are lucky enough to be using Boost, then Boost.DateTime in particular provides comparison operators for its `ptime` and gregorian date types.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


bool isDateInRange(int day, int month, int year, int startDay, int startMonth, int startYear, int endDay, int endMonth, int endYear){
    int entryDate = (year * 10000) + (month * 100) + day;
    int startDate = (startYear * 10000) + (startMonth * 100) + startDay;
    int endDate = (endYear * 10000) + (endMonth * 100) + endDay;

    if (entryDate >= startDate && entryDate <= endDate){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int day, month, year, startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear;

    // 11 June 2015
    // current date
    //day = 11; month = 6; year = 2015;
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);

    day = timePtr->tm_mday;
    //cout << "day: " << day;
    month = timePtr->tm_mon + 1;
    //cout << "month: " << month;
    year = timePtr->tm_year + 1900;
    //cout << "year: " << year;

    // 1 Jan 2015
    startDay = 1; startMonth = 1; startYear = 2015;

    // 12 July 2015
    endDay = 12; endMonth = 5; endYear = 2015;

    bool isInRange = isDateInRange(day, month, year, startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear);

    if (isInRange)
    {
        cout << "In range " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not in range " << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, currently it is almost impossible to read it.

Comment: Just code certainly cannot be considered an acceptable answer. Please provide some context.